# Where exactly do we place this postgresql.conf configuration file in spring boot application?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, encryption, orm

I am trying to encrypt a column in my prostrgres DB. The column name is "test" of type "bytea".

My enity code is below,

```
@ColumnTransformer(read = "pgp_sym_decrypt(" + "    test, "
        + "    current_setting('encrypt.key')"
        + ")", write = "pgp_sym_encrypt( " + "    ?, "
                + "    current_setting('encrypt.key')" + ") ")
@Column(columnDefinition = "bytea")
private String test;
```

postgresql.conf configuration file:
encrypt.key = 'Wow! So much security.

Placed the postgresql.conf configuration file in src/main/resources of spring boot appln. But the encryption.key value is not being picked up. And is there a way to pass the key using application.properties?

Comment: Do you save your ```key``` inside ```application.properties``` file? In that case you call your ```key``` using ```@Value``` annotation in your java class.

Comment: We cant inject Values or Autowire any objects in Entity right? Since entity is not a spring bean.

Comment: @EshwarKandari how ere you able to achieve it? I also want to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

`postgresql.conf` is the [configuration file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config.html) for the Postgres **server**. It's stored inside the [data directory](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/creating-cluster.html)  (aka "cluster") on the server.

You can't put it on the client side (where your application runs). It has no meaning there.

To change values in there, you need to edit the file (on the server) or use [`ALTER SYSTEM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altersystem.html).

If you want to change a configuration setting for the current session, use [`SET`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set.html) or [`set_config()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SET)

The latter two are probably the ones you are looking for to initialize the custom property for your encryption/decryption functions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I try to execute  ALTER SYSTEM SET encrypt.key = 'pwd123'; i'm getting  ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "encrypt.key". How do we create new config param ? Or is there any existing param where I can store my encryption key

Comment: Use `set_config()`

Comment: Thanks it helped, but I want to permanently store this config param in the file, not temporarily for this session. How to permanently store config param ?

Comment: set_config() is stroing the config param at that session level only. How to store it permanently? Kindly help.

Comment: For permanent storage, there is no way other than adding it to postgresql.conf as per current date of the comment

Answer (score 0):

The way to use encrypt.key, not only for current session, it's store it in postgresql.conf.

The correct place is at the end of this file, in the "Customized Options" section:

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CUSTOMIZED OPTIONS
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Add settings for extensions here
encrypt.key=123456
```

Reload the configuration of the database server:

```
systemctl reload postgresql.service
```

To testing if it's working correctly. Open a pgsql session and type:

```
mydb=# show encrypt.key;
 encrypt.key
-------------
 123456
(1 row)
```

Example of encrypt:

```
mydb=# select pgp_sym_encrypt('Hola mundo',current_setting('encrypt.key'));
                                                                      pgp_sym_encrypt
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 \xc30d04070302255230e388dfe25e7dd23b01c5b8e62d148088a3417d3c27ed2cc11655d863b271672b9f076fffb82f1a7f074f2ecbe973df04642cd7a4f76ca5cff4a13b9a71e7cc6e693827
(1 row)
```

Example of decrypt:

```
mydb=# select pgp_sym_decrypt('\xc30d04070302255230e388dfe25e7dd23b01c5b8e62d148088a3417d3c27ed2cc11655d863b271672b9f076fffb82f1a7f074f2ecbe973df04642cd7a4f76ca5cff4a13b9a71e7cc6e693827',current_setting('encrypt.key'));
 pgp_sym_decrypt
-----------------
 Hola mundo
(1 row)
```

Comment: But is this safe ? Storing the key inside the database, anyone can easily decrypt the data.